# Webpack converting files I don't want like .json files

Tags: node.js, webpack

I really just want webpack to take in the first three files but it's taking in many more.

It's even taking in the webpack.config.js which seems very wrong. I am not sure why this is happening.

I only want to convert `mutate`, `index` and `cli`.

Would any of you be able to help please?

```
[0] ./src/mutate.js 4.46 KiB {0} [built]
[5] ./src/index.js 463 bytes {0} [built]
[8] ./src/cli.js 238 bytes {0} [built]
[14] ./examples/input/0.json 1.81 KiB {0} [optional] [built] [failed] [1 error]
[15] ./examples/input/1.json 1.81 KiB {0} [optional] [built] [failed] [1 error]
[16] ./examples/input/2.json 1.81 KiB {0} [optional] [built] [failed] [1 error]
[17] ./examples/output/0.json 1.81 KiB {0} [optional] [built] [failed] [1 error]
[18] ./examples/output/1A.json 1.81 KiB {0} [optional] [built] [failed] [1 error]
[19] ./examples/output/1B.json 1.81 KiB {0} [optional] [built] [failed] [1 error]
[20] ./examples/output/2B.json 1.81 KiB {0} [optional] [built] [failed] [1 error]
[21] ./package.json 1.65 KiB {0} [optional] [built] [failed] [1 error]
[22] ./webpack.config.js 549 bytes {0} [optional] [built]
[30] (webpack)/buildin/harmony-module.js 573 bytes {0} [built]
[41] ./node_modules/colors/lib sync 160 bytes {0} [optional] [built]
[42] . sync ^\.\/.*$ 829 bytes {0} [built]
```

The config:

```
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: [
          /node_modules/, /__tests__/,
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.md$/,
        use: 'ignore-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: 'ignore-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
  },
};
```

Comment: It converts json because of this: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/WebpackOptionsDefaulter.js#L80 - it is a default behaviour. There are not enough docs to show how to disable this. How do you run your webpack? which options do you give to the cli?

Comment: No CLI options and it is bundling all of my json even after trying to ignore the json. I am not sure what other details you need? 

It is also bundling my javascript test files. : ( @MatheusSilva

Comment: wuuuutttttt, this does not even make sense, at all. Good luck on this sir, i'll keep an eye on this anwer too, im interested!